# Loading context in Spring using web.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml

Is there a way that a context can be loaded using web.xml in a Spring MVC application?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

From the spring docs

Spring can be easily integrated into any Java-based web framework. All you need to do is to declare the **ContextLoaderListener** in your **web.xml** and use a **contextConfigLocation**  to set which context files to load.

The `<context-param>`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can then use the WebApplicationContext to get a handle on your beans.

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servlet.getServletContext());
SomeBean someBean = (SomeBean) ctx.getBean("someBean");
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html for more info

Comment: How to access the context? and Are you saying that context will be loaded with Spring Context as soon as the application start? Please clarify because I am new to Spring,. Thanks for you response

Comment: Here is the link for latest APIs related to WebApplicationContextUtils. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html

Answer (score 34):

You can also specify context location relatively to current classpath, which may be preferable

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: What is the significance of the `*`? It doesn't work without it: `IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/>classpath:/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/>classpath:/applicationContext.xml]`

Comment: I just found a blog post answering my question about `classpath*` [here](http://www.gridshore.nl/2008/05/13/spring-application-context-loading-tricks/).

Answer (score 17):

You can also load the context while defining the servlet itself (**WebApplicationContext**)

```xml
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/*.xml
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

rather than (**ApplicationContext**)

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

or can do both together.

Drawback of just using WebApplicationContext is that it will load context only for this particular Spring entry point (`DispatcherServlet`) where as with above mentioned methods context will be loaded for multiple entry points (Eg. `Webservice Servlet, REST servlet` etc)

Context loaded by `ContextLoaderListener` will infact be a parent context to that loaded specifically for DisplacherServlet . So basically you can load all your business service, data access or repository beans in application context and separate out your controller, view resolver beans to WebApplicationContext.