# spring java and customize configuration file

Tags: java, spring

i would like to include a xml file for my web app configuration. i would like to use the configurations in my controller and probably taglibs. where should i include this config file and how can i access it?

this is my proj tree directory:

```
web proj/
   |
   |---Java Resource/
   |         |
   |         |---src
   |         |---resources
   |                |
   |                |---messages_en.properties
   |                |---messages_de.properties
   |
   |---build/
   |
   |---WebContent/
   |       |
   |       |---css/
   |       |---images/
   |       |---js/
   |       |---META-INF/
   |       |---themes/
   |       |---WEB-INF/
   |       |      |
   |       |      |---jsp/
   |       |      |---lib/
   |       |      |---web-servlet.xml
   |       |      |---spring-security.xml
   |       |      |---tiles.xml
   |       |      |---web.xml
   |       |---index.jsp
   |---build.properties
   |---build.xml
```

many thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451377/loading-context-in-spring-using-web-xml  Your Spring config in this case would go in WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

Comment: hi tks for the reply. however i was wondering, should i read from the resource dir instead?

Comment: the resource file refers to Java Resource/resources dir