# The requested resource is not available on project launch spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Please why I am getting the requested resource is not found on project start up even though everything seems alright

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Please assist me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the Spring context with org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener, not Log4jConfigListener (or try out Spring Boot)

See [Loading context in Spring using web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451377/loading-context-in-spring-using-web-xml)

Comment: Can I integrate Spring Boot into my project and still maintain the normal structure of my projecct

Comment: I have done it but still thesame resource not found problem